# Violation of specific constraint in Pulp

Tags: optimization, modeling, python, pulp

I have successfully implemented a program where I allocate **N** `truck drivers` to **M** `gathering hubs` for each one of the days of the week. The constraints I have implemented are:

1. - A driver cannot work more than 6 days, i.e. 1 day to rest
2. - A driver cannot be allocated in more than 1 hubs for each day
3. - Each hub must satisfy its driver requirements for each day of the week
4. - A driver must work his days at one hub instead of many.

The program runs smoothly, satisfies the overall objective and outputs a schedule for each hub-driver pair.

**However,** the **extra constraint** that forces the drivers to work at one hub (constraint 4), instead of their working days being split into many hubs, is violated and assigns some drivers to many hubs.

How can that be fixed?

Please find my code below.

Thank you

````
import pulp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

day_requirement = [[3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3],
             [3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5],
             [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
             [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
             [2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
             [6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4],
             [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]]

total_day_requirements = ([sum(x) for x in zip(*day_requirement)])

hub_names = {0: 'Hub 1',
             1: 'Hub 2',
             2: 'Hub 3',
             3: 'Hub 4',
             4: 'Hub 5',
             5: 'Hub 6',
             6: 'Hub 7'}

total_drivers = max(total_day_requirements)  # number of drivers
total_hubs = len(day_requirement)  # number of hubs

days = 7

def schedule(drivers, hubs, day_requirement):
    # driver_names = ilm_riders['riders']
    driver_names = ['Driver_{}'.format(i) for i in range(drivers)]
    var = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('VAR', (range(hubs), range(drivers), range(days)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
    problem = pulp.LpProblem('shift', pulp.LpMinimize)

    obj = None
    for h in range(hubs):
        for driver in range(drivers):
            for day in range(days):
                obj += var[h][driver][day]
    problem += obj

    #  we add binary variables z indicating if a driver is active on a hub:
    z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Z', (range(hubs), range(drivers)), 0, 1, 'Binary')
    # minimize the sum of drivers active on hubs
    for h in range(hubs):
        for driver in range(drivers):
            obj += z[h][driver]
    problem += obj

    # Add constraints to connect z with VAR:
    for driver in range(drivers):
        for h in range(hubs):
            problem += z[h][driver] <= pulp.lpSum(var[h][driver][day] for day in range(days))
            problem += days * z[h][driver] >= pulp.lpSum(var[h][driver][day] for day in range(days))

    # if a driver works one day at a hub, he cannot work that day in a different hub obviously
    for driver in range(drivers):
        for day in range(days):
            problem += pulp.lpSum([var[h][driver][day] for h in range(hubs)]) <= 1

    # schedule must satisfy daily requirements of each hub
    for day in range(days):
        for h in range(hubs):
            problem += pulp.lpSum(var[h][driver][day] for driver in range(drivers)) == \
                       day_requirement[h][day]

    # a driver cannot work more than 6 days
    for driver in range(drivers):
        problem += pulp.lpSum([var[h][driver][day] for day in range(days) for h in range(hubs)]) \
                   <= 6

    # for driver in range(drivers):
    #     problem += pulp.lpSum([var[h][driver][day] for day in range(days) for h in range(hubs)]) >= 5

    # Solve problem. We have a very complex solution so we set a timeout at 10secs.
    status = problem.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False, timeLimit=10))

    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([hub_names.values(), driver_names], names=['Hub', 'Driver'])

    col = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    # col = ['Day_{}'.format(i) for i in range(days)]
    dashboard = pd.DataFrame(0, idx, col)

    for h in range(hubs):
        for driver in range(drivers):
            for day in range(days):
                if var[h][driver][day].value() > 0.0:
                    dashboard.loc[hub_names[h], driver_names[driver]][col[day]] = 1

    # print(dashboard)

    driver_table = dashboard.groupby('Driver').sum()
    driver_sums = driver_table.sum(axis=1)
    # print(driver_sums)

    day_sums = driver_table.sum(axis=0)
    # print(day_sums)

    print("Status", pulp.LpStatus[status])
    return driver_sums, dashboard, status


driver_sums, dashboard, status = schedule(total_drivers, total_hubs, day_reqs)
while (driver_sums > 6).any() or status == -1:
    print('Staus infeasible OR one or more drivers have been allocated more than 6 days of work so '
          'we must add one '
          'driver: {}->{}'.format(total_drivers, total_drivers + 1))
    total_drivers += 1
    driver_sums, dashboard, status = schedule(total_drivers, total_hubs, day_reqs)


# dashboard = schedule(total_drivers, total_hubs, day_reqs)
driver_table = dashboard.groupby('Driver').sum()
driver_sums = driver_table.sum(axis=1)
# print(driver_sums)
day_sums = driver_table.sum(axis=0)

```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce linear constraints:
$$\sum_{\text{h}} z[\text{h}][\text{driver}] \le 1 \quad\text{for each driver}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that when i add this constraint, then constraint 1, i.e. A driver cannot work more than 6 days, i.e. 1 day to rest, seems to be violated and only a few drivers work 6 days; most of them end up working 1-5 days. Can this somehow be amended?

Comment: How does working 1-5 days violate the "cannot work more than 6 days" rule?

Comment: You’re right. Please Let me rephrase: I would like the truck drivers to work exactly 6 days per week and 1 day off. However, if I set the constraint to == 6 the problem seems to be unsolvable (?)

Comment: The requirements add up to 134, which is not a multiple of 6.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I literally have no idea what that means

Comment: If each driver works exactly 6 days, that would satisfy 6*total_drivers requirements, but the total of all requirements is 134, which is not a multiple of 6, so the problem is infeasible.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. What do you suggest in such cases?

Comment: I modified the total_drivers_requirements to be a multiple of 6, i.e. 144, but still the problem cannot be solved

Comment: What new requirement values did you use?

Comment: day_reqs = [[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3],
            [3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5],
            [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            [2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            [6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4],
            [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]]

Comment: Those requirements imply exactly $144/6=24$ drivers, which would all be used on Monday.  But Hub 7 needs 5 drivers on Monday and 6 drivers on Sunday, so some driver would need to serve multiple hubs.

Comment: The thing is that with 24 drivers, the solver prompts 'Status Infeasible'

Comment: Yes, I described in the last comment why the problem is infeasible if you want exactly six days per driver and at most one hub per driver.

Comment: I set <=6 days instead of ==6 and still get infeasible.

Comment: For the new requirements and 24 drivers, <= 6 implies == 6.  The minimum number of drivers turns out to be 30.

Comment: How do you get that? If I include the proposed constraint and set drivers=30, I get the following working days/driver 

Driver_0     6
Driver_1     4
Driver_10    6
Driver_11    5
Driver_12    5
Driver_13    4
Driver_14    4
Driver_15    6
Driver_16    5
Driver_17    2
Driver_18    6
Driver_19    4
Driver_2     6
Driver_20    3
Driver_21    3
Driver_22    6
Driver_23    3
Driver_24    4
Driver_25    6
Driver_26    3
Driver_27    3
Driver_28    6
Driver_29    6
Driver_3     4
Driver_4     6
Driver_5     5
Driver_6     6
Driver_7     5
Driver_8     6
Driver_9     6

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to find out the number of drivers so as each one to work 6 days even that means that the demand must be tweaked somehow.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  My minimum of 30 drivers is from using the new requirements and imposing the new constraint from my answer, but without changing <= 6 to == 6.  For your most recent comment, please open a separate question.  You will need to quantify how much the demand can be tweaked.